# How can I edit a field in an arbitrary row in a livecode datagrid programatically?

Tags: datagrid, livecode

I'm working on a LiveCode project that displays a modal with a DataGrid table.

If the user selects one or more rows in the DataGrid and clicks the OK button, the selected rows are copied to another DataGrid table in another stack.

I want to open an edit field in the first of the copied rows in the other stack.

I've found the EditFieldText command, but haven't been able to figure out what to provide as the first parameter (pField).

I am assuming that the other parameters (pIndex and pKey), are the DataGrid row index and column name, respectively.

This is the code in my OK button:

```
on mouseUp
   lock screen
   put the dgHiLitedLines of group selectComponentGrid into rowNumbers
   put the dgData of group selectComponentGrid into rows
   put true into firstTime
   repeat for each item rowNumber in rowNumbers
      put rows[rowNumber] into row 
      dispatch "AddData" to group bomGrid of card inventoryItem of stack inventory with row
      if firstTime is true then
         # Set focus to this row's quantity field.
         put "quantity" into colName
         put the result into lineNo -- the result contains the index of the new row
         send "EditCellOfIndex colName lineNo" to group bomGrid on card "inventoryItem" of stack "inventory"
         # At this point the result contains "no control exists for index column"
         put false into firstTime
      end if
      #end if
   end repeat
   unlock screen
   close this stack
end mouseUp
```

I have spent several hours reading LiveCode documentation and searching. I've found a lot of articles, but no explanation of how to actually do this.

I'm using LiveCode 9.0.0-dp-4|Build 15003 Community Edition on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

**Edit 2017-01-17 13:23:** 
I found the EditCellOfIndex command, modified my code to use it based on various examples that I found, and have had no success with it either. 
I have updated the code above to reflect the changes that I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about syntax (I'm still getting used to the LiveCode syntax).
I was using the wrong syntax for the EditCellOfIndex message.

I also needed to move sending the message out of the loop adding rows to the other DataGrid because the next add closes the phantom edit field.

Thanks to sritcp over on the LiveCode forums for the syntax catch.
Here is the functional code:

```
on mouseUp
   lock screen
   put empty into lineNo
   put the dgHiLitedLines of group selectComponentGrid into rowNumbers
   put the dgData of group selectComponentGrid into rows
   repeat for each item rowNumber in rowNumbers
      put rows[rowNumber] into row
      Dispatch "AddData" to group bomGrid of card inventoryItem of stack inventory with row
      if lineNo is empty then
         put the result into lineNo
      end if
   end repeat
   if lineNo is not empty then
      # Set focus to the first new row's quantity field.
      dispatch "EditCellOfIndex" \
            to group bomGrid on card "inventoryItem" of stack "inventory" \
            with "quantity", lineNo
   end if
   unlock screen
   close this stack
end mouseUp
```